# How to fix vm export error in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

When I export VM at the end I have this error.

Failed to export appliance /home/host/VirtualBox VMs/heh.ova.

Could not create the exported medium 'heh-disk001.vmdk' (VERR_DEV_IO_ERROR).

Result Code: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004)
Component: MediumWrap
Interface: IMedium {4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda}

Edit: I run VM VirtualBox as administrator